# How to make Sublime Text open several files in one window?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Using Sublime Text 3 on the Centos 7.6 (Linux) operating system.

When I use Sublime Text to open files from the command prompt:

```
[root@localhost www]# sublime sitemap.php
[root@localhost www]# sublime robots.txt
```

The files are opened in 2 Sublime Text windows, even when the `open_files_in_new_window` setting is set to `false`.

How do I make Sublime Text open the files in one window?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @mattst,centos7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use a Linux distribution and when I open files from the command line they do open in the same window.

The command you are using on the command line is `sublime` I suspect that starts Sublime Text with the `--new-window` option.

Look to see if you have the `/usr/bin/subl` file on your system. If you do then use `subl` instead of `sublime` on the command line and see if that opens the files in the same window.

If `/usr/bin/subl` is not on your system then you can create it like this:

Note: `/usr/bin/subl` is just the Sublime Text launcher which is automatically installed on Debian based Linux distributions.

Add these 2 lines to a new file and save it as `/home/user/subl`:

Note: Change the path to `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text` if need be.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text "$@"
```

Then run these commands as a super user or with `sudo`, whatever is easiest with Centos:

```
$ chown root:root subl
$ mv subl /usr/bin/
```

Now you should be able to use `subl` on the command line to open files in Sublime Text and they should open in the same window, e.g.:

```
$ subl sitemap.php
$ subl robots.txt
```

Comment: You can also just `sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl` (adjust paths as appropriate) if you want a one-liner.

Comment: @mattst,there is `/usr/bin/subl` in centos 7.6.I found the problem:I run `sublime` or `subl` as normal user,everything is ok.When I run  `sublime` or `subl` as `root`,will open several windows.  How to make sublime open only 1 window when `root` run sublime?